# did you know a method to show this value using python

Tags: python, numbers

i know floor in python :

```
floor(0.2) #---> 0
```

but i want to get :

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 #---> 1
 11 12 13 ...  20 # --->2
 21 22 23 ... 30 #--->3
```

has a method to get this value ,

thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> (21 + 9) // 10
3
>>> (30 + 9) // 10
3
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. `>>> (30 + 9) // 10`
`3`
`>>> (39 + 9) // 10`
`4`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution (without the need to import `math` module) is:

> (x-1) // 10 + 1

which will make sure you get an integer (thanks to `//`). But if you insist on using `floor()`, then here you go:

```
import math
math.floor ( (x - 1) / 10. ) + 1
```

For example:

- `x = 1`: floor ( (1 - 1) / 10. ) + 1 = floor (0) + 1 = 1
- `x = 9`: floor ( (9 - 1) / 10. ) + 1 = floor (8 / 10) + 1 = 1
- `x = 10`: floor ( (10 - 1) / 10. ) + 1 = floor (9 / 10) + 1 = 1
- `x = 11`: floor ( (11 - 1) / 10. ) + 1 = floor (10 / 10) + 1 = 2
- and so on...

**EDIT:**

I have updated my answer and got rid of division importing (which simplifies the solution), following the advice of [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau). Thanks!

**EDIT2:**

Updated my answer with `(x-1) // 10 + 1)` solution, which does not need additional modules and looks like the faster one.

Comment: Simpler to just use `math.floor ( (x - 1) / 10. ) + 1` and not worry about `import division`. Even better to use faster integer division as shown in @Ignacio's answer and avoid calling the `math` function.